# Java - Importing two ParseException, one from commons CLI and the basic text.ParseException

Tags: java, date, parsing, exception

I´ve got a quite annoying problem.
I´ve to use `import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;` for the commandline parsing, but I also have to use `import java.text.ParseException;` to be able to use `parse(some String)` out of `SimpleDateFormat`. But since they both carry ParseException within it´s name, it is not possible for me to just use throw ParseException behind a method even if I tried to etablish a class instance of those.

I didn´t found a solution or someone who had a problem close to mine, so it´d be nice to get some help.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. You have a name collision, so you can `import` **only *one*** of them. What you can do is use the fully qualified name of the other, for example `import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;` and then

```
void myMethod throws java.text.ParseException {
    // ...
}
```

to use the other `ParseException`.

Comment: Thank you that worked for me, but somehow now when I use parse(some String) and I use a valid input, it tells me `Unparseable date`, but when I use try-catch around it, it works just fine, but I have to do this for a university project and one of the rules states that we are not allowed to use try-catch. :/

Comment: Weird. Can you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? @GradleUser1